# warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast in array

Tags: c, arrays, warnings

I'm working with dynamic arrays and this is the declaration:

```
int *vetor = (int *) malloc (tam*sizeof(int));

vetorAleatorio (vetor, tam); //chamando função abaixo
```

but when I try to pass it as parameter to this function:

```
void vetorAleatorio(int **vet, int size) {
 int i;

 for (i=0; i<size; i++)
       vet[i] = rand() %1000;}
```

I have the following errors:

```
[Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
[Warning] passing arg 1 of `vetorAleatorio' from incompatible pointer type
```

Someone know how this is happening?

Comment: This is just a comment, but avoid casting malloc in C [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Comment: Usually, you have a double pointer argument (**vet) if you are going to allocate within the function and make use of it outside the function.  int *vetor = Null;  vetorAlea(&vetor, tam); //allocated in function....

Comment: but you MUST cast malloc in C++ Source..... (sigh...)

Answer (score 5):

Your function syntax:

```
void vetorAleatorio(int **vet, int size)
```

should be:

```
void vetorAleatorio(int *vet, int size)
                        ^ 
                        // remove one *
```

> **[Warning]** assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

if you use double `*` as  `int **` for `vet`, then its type mismatch as follows:

```
vet[i] = rand() %1000
   ^        ^ 
   |          int  // rand() %1000 returns a int
 type is int* 
 // vet[i] ==  *(vet + i) == *(pointer to pointer of int) = pointer int = int*
```

> **Warning-2:** passing arg 1 of `vetorAleatorio' from incompatible pointer type

Understand In your code you according to `void vetorAleatorio(int **vet, int size)` declaration you are calling function in wrong way: `vetorAleatorio (vetor, tam);`, you are passing address of int = pointer to int, and argument need address of pointer to int = pointer to pointer to int.

You just need one rectification as I suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

`int **vet` declares that the `vet` argument is a pointer to a pointer to `int`.  i.e. an array of arrays of integers.  It looks like you just want to pass a pointer to a single vector so you should declare the argument as type `int*` instead

```
void vetorAleatorio(int *vet, int size) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function signature for `vetorAleatorio` is wrong - change:

```
void vetorAleatorio(int **vet, int size)
```

to:

```
void vetorAleatorio(int *vet, int size)
```

Also note that you should never cast the result of `malloc` in C, so change:

```
int *vetor = (int *) malloc (tam*sizeof(int));
```

to:

```
int *vetor = malloc (tam*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

`vetor` is of type `int *`, where `veteroAleatorio` is expecting an `int **`

You should have

```
void vetorAleatorio(int *vet, int size) {
 int i;

 for (i=0; i<size; i++)
       vet[i] = rand() %1000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `*`.  This should work:

```
void vetorAleatorio(int *vet, int size)
```

You are passing in a pointer to an int (the variable `vetor`), so your function declaration should accept a pointer to an int.